# how to deal with three sets of SEM results on the same causal model

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling

I built a causal model for investigating help-seeking. I have collected data to test my model through SEM. I have collected data three times from the same population over three months (using the same questionnaire).

I was able to obtain a good fit for each collected data set. However, for example, one of the path (relationship) between concept A and B is not significant for the first data set, but this relationship is significant for the other two data sets. However, many of the relationships are consistently significant for three data sets.

I can exclude the non-significant (NS) paths and re-run SEM and obtain a better model fit. However, I guess I should keep these NS paths and discuss why they are not significant, and highlight the ones that are consistently significant.

What do you think about this method? If you were able to test a causal model with three different data sets, would you discard the NS paths? How would you organize your results, and interpret them?

Best!

Here is my Mplus code:

```
VARIABLE:

  NAMES = X1-X41;!X59;
  USEVARIABLES ARE X1-X4 X5 X7 X10 X12-X41; !x1=id x2=g x3=t
  GROUPING IS X3 (1 = 1 2 = 2 3 = 3);
  cluster is X1;
ANALYSIS:
  TYPE IS complex;
  ESTIMATOR=ML;

model:

  REL BY X4 X5 X7 X10;
  TS BY X12-X15;
  INT BY X16-X18;
  COSTS BY X19-X22;
  BENFS BY X23-X25;
  INST BY X26-X28;
  EXEC BY X29-X31;
  MAST BY X32-X35; 
  PERM BY X36-X41;

model 1:

  BENFS ON TS REL MAST (a1);
  COSTS ON TS REL PERM (a2);

  EXEC ON PERM COSTS(a3);
  INST ON MAST BENFS(a4);

  INT ON BENFS COSTS MAST REL(a5);


model 2:
  BENFS ON TS REL MAST (b1);
  COSTS ON TS REL PERM (b2);

  EXEC ON PERM COSTS(b3);
  INST ON MAST BENFS(b4);

  INT ON BENFS COSTS MAST REL(b5);

model 3:
  BENFS ON TS REL MAST (c1);
  COSTS ON TS REL PERM (c2);

  EXEC ON PERM COSTS(c3);
  INST ON MAST BENFS(c4);

  INT ON BENFS COSTS MAST REL(c5);


model constraint:
 a1 = b1;
 a1 = c1;

 a2 = b2;
 a2 = c2;

 a3 = b3;
 a3 = c3;

 a4 = b4;
 a4 = c4;

 a5 = b5;
 a5 = c5;
```

Comment: If you want to include longitudinal effects then you can set up a longitudinal model. You could also fit a single model using a multilevel SEM.

Comment: @JeremyMiles with multiple datasets my purpose is to be able to more strongly argue that the model is valid one, I am not interested in longitudinal effects.

Comment: In that case I'd set it up as a clustered / multilevel model, with the datasets appended. You can then estimate the parameters in all three models simultaneously. What software do you use?

Comment: @JeremyMiles I use mplus, could you please post a more detailed answer, so that I can assign bounty? I appreciate any further explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of what you have as a study that has been replicated three times. The problem with doing the study three times is that it is hard to distinguish between random variation and real differences. If these were different people we could combine the three studies in something like an Individual Patient Data meta-analysis (IPDA).  We can do something like that in Mplus, using multiple groups.

We stack the data so that it is tall, and we have a time identifier.  I've put a really simple example, with one variable, on Dropbox, here: https://db.tt/GSdAUCTt

We have three variables: id, which goes from 1 to 100, and because we replicated the study three times, each person appears three times. t, which is time - it's 1 for the first time, 2 for the second, etc. Then a single variable, which I've called x.

Here's my variable set up in Mplus:

```
  VARIABLE:
    NAMES ARE id t x;
    USEVARIABLES ARE id t x;
    GROUPING IS t (1 = 1 2 = 2 3 = 3);
```

The grouping tells Mplus that I have three groups, called 1, 2 and 3.  However, these groups aren't indepdendent - and I need to tell MPlus that, using the cluster option.

```
cluster is id;
```

Then we fit a multiple group model in Mplus. This means that we estimate each parameter in each group. In my model, I'm just going to estimate the mean and variance of x in each group. Your model will be more complex, but the results will be exactly the same as if you estimated the three groups separately.

```
  model:
  model 1:
  x (var1);
  [x] (mean1) ;

  model 2:
  x (var2);
  [x] (mean2) ;

  model 3:
  x (var3);
  [x] (mean3) ;
```

Now I've estimated my three groups. But I think that all the parameters should be the same. I labelled each parameter, so now I constrain them to be equal, and I'll estimate a single parameter across the three groups. To do that, I add:

```
 model constraint:
 var1 = var2;
 var1 = var3;

 mean1 = mean2;
 mean1 = mean3;
```

Checking my model results, I have the same values, standard errors, etc, in all three groups.

```
                                  Two-Tailed
                    Estimate       S.E.  Est./S.E.    P-Value

Group 1

 Means
    X                  4.873      0.166     29.303      0.000

 Variances
    X                  8.174      0.447     18.296      0.000

Group 2

 Means
    X                  4.873      0.166     29.303      0.000

 Variances
    X                  8.174      0.447     18.296      0.000

Group 3

 Means
    X                  4.873      0.166     29.303      0.000

 Variances
    X                  8.174      0.447     18.296      0.000
```

How do I know that it was OK to combine them? I can do a chi-square difference test, and test if my null hypothesis that the parameters don't differ across the three groups. That's done with the chi-square difference test of the first model against the second. (Note that it's an MLR estimator, so you need to do the MLR difference test - which is described here: https://www.statmodel.com/chidiff.shtml There are excel spreadsheets floating around the internet to do it for you.

My Mplus file can also be found here: https://db.tt/aXjeLLDc

It might be the case that there is some sort of learning effect, and that you can't constrain the means to be equal across groups. If that happens, I don't think it's a problem.

Based on the comment below, you can name constraints for more elaborate models. The variables have the same name - it's the group that identifies which study it is from

```
model 1:
a on b (ab1);
a on c (ac1);
a on d (ad1);

model 2:
a on b (ab2);
a on c (ac2);
a on d (ad2);

model 3:
a on b (ab3);
a on c (ac3);
a on d (ad3);

model constraint: 
ab1 = ab2;
ab1 = ab3;

ac1 = ac2;
ac1 = ac3;

ad1 = ad2;
ad1 = ad3;
```

Comment: is the main idea behind your design to test if these three models are significantly different from each other or not? Is this why you constraint them to be the same? So, at the end basically I will have a single model results since they are all equalized?

Comment: also, what would be the difference if I ONLY do a chi-square difference among three models and try to see which model fits the best, and just use it? I guess you combined all three sets for a single model?

Comment: The purpose of the chi-square test is to compare the three models and see if you can find differences. If you can't find differences, then you merge the three into one by constraining everything to be equal. There are two advantages of this: First, you have one model, not three, so you have an easier time. Second, your parameters are all estimated using all of the data, so should have smaller standard errors and you have more power to detect your effects.

Comment: in my model I have these, for example, `A ON B C D`, then how can I constrain everything to be equal in this case? Should I have like `A1 ON B1 C1 D1` and `A2 ON B2 C2 D2`, then have `model constraint: A1 = A2;` ? I really appreciate your help sir! Also, is there any book reference that I can particularly use for this case?

Comment: I'll add to the question, because I can't put formatiing here.

Comment: I wonder if the data should come from the same individuals for this analysis to be valid? For example, what if I have 2 participant missing in the first data set, and I have 10 new participants in the 3rd data set? Would this bother the analysis?

Comment: Yes. You don't?  Oh, you don't. I read "same population" as "same sample".  Then just drop the cluster line.

Comment: _Almost_ same population.. not  all students fill out questionnaire at each data collection; therefore, there are some minor differences. So, you recommend just deleting `cluster is id;` instead of eliminating the additional participants to keep the same set of participants in all three data set?

Comment: Do you have unique IDs for the students? If so, then leave it in.

Comment: yes I have unique IDs for the students, then I will just leave it as it is although I have slight differences in terms of participants across data sets? Sorry for too many questions!

Comment: :) That's OK. Differences are fine. If everyone was different, then it's the same as not having the cluster line.

Comment: sir, I tried the analysis that you suggested. However, it behaves weird. When I do cluster and three model, I obtain three result sets for three separate models (actually they are the same model), and all the relationships among the latent variables in each model are NS. For testing, I run ALL data with a single model (no cluster) and model fit was great with significant relationships as I expected. Do you think I am missing sth? I have posted my mplus code in the original post. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Yes, you need to separate the on statements into separate lines. When you write:  BENFS ON TS REL MAST (a1); you are making the regression estimate for BENFS on TS equal to BENFS on REL and BENFS on MAST.   Eac predictor has its own line in my code.

Comment: I fixed it but still getting the same weird results, almost nothing is significant, and the model cannot converge (does not show any fit measures). I tested the code with a single model (without cluster or grouping), and I get good results (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2eU5Y6sEfJ7Y21UTkNHYzRNaUU/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the latest code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2eU5Y6sEfJ7eERJLVZiN0R6SGM/view?usp=sharing

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I can't access Google drive from where I am (thanks, corporate firewall!), but if you have no restrictions and you remove the cluster line, your three model results should be exactly the same (or very nearly) as the three separate models

Comment: this is what I see in that case `THE STANDARD ERRORS OF THE MODEL PARAMETER ESTIMATES COULD NOT BE
     COMPUTED.  THE MODEL MAY NOT BE IDENTIFIED.  CHECK YOUR MODEL.
     PROBLEM INVOLVING PARAMETER 132.

     THE CONDITION NUMBER IS      -0.315D-06.

     THE ROBUST CHI-SQUARE COULD NOT BE COMPUTED.` I think I gave up :(

Comment: Don't give up! We're so close. Let's take a look and see what parameter 328 is. It's the covariance of INT and INST in Group 3.  Not sure why that is. Can you run the three separate models and put them on google drive?

Comment: Your structural model is hard to work out. What happens if you run it as a saturated structural model (i.e. all latent vars allowed to covary).

Comment: I think I finally made it! Thanks for your help! I have one question: if I set the path coefficients free vs if I constraint them all equal, I obtain slightly different coefficient values. Do you know what does that mean? Which one am I supposed to report?

Comment: Well done. If the constraints are tenable (via chi-square test) report the constrained. Otherwise unconstrained.

Comment: may I kindly ask what does it mean constraining? I know how to do it, but I am not sure meaning of it, and discuss it in my results? I appreciate any help! BTW, chi-square test showed difference only for one path.

Comment: When you write ab1 = ab2, you have constrained those two parameters to be equal.

Comment: when I constrain them to be equal, and if I find a significant difference based on the chi-square test for a specific path, does this mean at the second model this path is significantly different than the first model? I am just having hard time to interpret this..

Comment: Yes. The chi-square difference (likeihood ratio) test when you add that constraint is the test that the two paths are equal. (I'm not sure what you mean by "chi-square test for a specific path".)

Comment: sir, may I kindly ask you to help me answer these questions (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202225/how-to-interpret-the-results-when-the-models-are-constrained-to-be-invariant-in). I have been checking several resources but could not find the answers. Your help is greatly appreciated! (this is for my dissertation)