# How to interpret the results when the models are constrained to be invariant in multi-group modeling

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, mplus

I have constrained two models to be equal, and based on the  $\chi^2$ test there is no difference between the models, they are invariant. These two models contain exactly the same path coefficients. However, the first model uses the data obtained at the 2nd month, and the second model uses the data obtained at the 4th month from the same participants.

I obtained the path coefficients in the `Mplus` results for each model separately, and they are slightly different across the models. However, I get only one set of model fit indices.

How can I obtain two sets of results?

Also, when I run only one model instead of multi-group modeling, the path coefficients are different from what I have obtained for that specific model when doing multi-group model analysis.

Can anyone explain the differences between these models to me? Why do I get different results when they are constrained to be invariant in multi-group modeling? Should I report path coefficients values for two models?

If the $\chi^2$ difference test shows no significant difference across the models, does it make sense to combine all data and run a single model?

Comment: Can you clarify some things? You say you've constrained two models, but then you say you have two sets of coefficients, and one set of fit indices.

Comment: You say that your coefficients differ when you use two groups with everything free. That shouldn't happen - there are probably some constraints that Mplus has included by default. Perhaps intercepts or thresholds.  Put tech1 in output and check the parameters are all different. (I guess it could be missing data too - full information ML in Mplus is model based, so changing your model will change your data (as it were). Put sampstat in the output section and make sure the sample stats are the same.

Comment: @JeremyMiles What if there are slight changes in the sample? I have around 320 in each sample, but around 40 of the participants are not matching, do you think this is the reason why I am getting different coeffs when the models are set free or constrained? As always, thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm confused now. If these are the same people they should not be treated as multiple groups because they are not independent. (Unless you're using complex samples).

Comment: @JeremyMiles you mean I cannot conduct multi-group analysis if the participants are composed of almost the same people? Here is my situation: I administered the same questionnaire at two different time points, but of course there was not perfect match across time points in terms of participants. The chi-square test showed that there is NO significant difference across time points (parameters are constrained vs parameters are set free). So, I included that the hypothesized causal relationships hold across different time points. Does this make sense?

Comment: to add further, in my scenario then is it reasonable if I attribute the different coefficient values to the slight differences in two populations?

Comment: The chi-square test isn't right, because you have violated the independence assumption. (The p-value is probably too high). Set it up as a longitudinal model, and you can do the same thing. Instead of a -> b for two groups, you have four variables, a1, b1, a2, b2, and you do something like: b1 on a1; b2 on a2; a1 with a2; b1 with b2.

Comment: @JeremyMiles ohh, I see. What you mean is that I need to check longitudinal structural invariance, is that right? Do I have to have exact same sample in this case? Is it tolerable if there are some changes in participants at two time points? 

Also, do you think it is okay if I just conduct separate SEM analysis for each time point, and never bother to compare them? My focus is mainly the causal relationships, and all relationships (except one of them) hold at each time point? What would be your recommendations?

Comment: Yes, you need to check longitudinal invariance. You'll have some missing data, but that's OK.  If you have invariance and you test them together, you'll have more power.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37570/discussion-between-renakre-and-jeremy-miles).

Comment: @JeremyMiles Sir, thanks for the answers. My problem is how will I know "if I have invariance"? As you said I cannot use chi-square test because groups are the same sample, then what to do?

Comment: You can use the chi-square statistic in a multiple group model, because you don't have multiple group data. You have longitudinal data, so you can use the chi-square to test for longitudinal invariance.

Comment: @JeremyMiles oh I see now. Is it normal that the model fit indices decrease with longitudinal model?

Comment: Decrease with respect to what?

Comment: @JeremyMiles It decreases compared to when I run the model separately per time point. I shared my [code here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8aAWA7z9HVPOdHuSBQSUb0ViQBDc3A7BpDmkgYzsUM/edit?usp=sharing), do you see any problems? .

Comment: What decreased, relative to what?

Comment: @JeremyMiles for example CFI decreased from .966 to .940. Maybe this is normal since the latent variables are doubled because of two timpoints (e.g., a1 and a2)? I just want to make this is normal, and I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: Sir, one last question: so I will have the coefficient values for both time points (e.g., a1->b1: 0.255 and a2->b2: 0.302), and I will need to report those, is that right? Also, on these coefficients, I have more power since I constrained them to be equal?

Comment: If they're constrained to be be equal, you'll have one value to report, not two.

Comment: @JeremyMiles You are right! STDYX results confused me! However, should I use MODEL RESULTS or the STDYX results? All latent variables are based on likert data (1-5 scale). I believe I can go with unstandardized coefficients, is that right?

Comment: Table 3 in this paper is how we solved it on one occasion: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26678071

Comment: @JeremyMiles this will give me some ideas, thanks!

Comment: @JeremyMiles the r2 values are different for each timepoint, I wonder if this is normal?

Comment: They should be the same if you constrain everything (including error variances) to be equal.

Comment: @JeremyMiles does this mean I constrain the BY expressions?

Comment: Everything. Variances, covariances and regressions.

Comment: @JeremyMiles yes it worked, and now STDYX values for 2 time points are the same as well. Model fit indices got worse slightly but still a good fit. I wonder if constraining everything has any disadvantages or limitations that I should discuss? I just wonder if what I do is a common practice.

Comment: If it's not significantly worse, it's a more parsimonious model, and so your parameter estimates are better (there's a paper by Mooijart and Bentler (I think) on that.)

Comment: @JeremyMiles Ohh, after I constrained everything, I just noticed that chi-square difference became significant. I think I will constrain only the path coefficients, and live with it :) Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!